# Target for Hyperlinks in questions and comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks

Is it possible to set the default target for hyperlinks provided in questions and comments to new window (`target="_BLANK"`).

I don't know that this is done on SO or any other SE site, and could just be a preference of mine. I don't like having to hit the back button to go back to the question or comment that lead me to the external site, or other SE question. There are some sites that only think of themselves and disable the "back" feature.

If not can it be added as an option to the editor that allows you to set the target to current or new window?

Comment: Aaron Bertrand's [answer](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/1017/25092) pretty much sums up the situation.  If this were to happen (and I think it unlikely), it would be a network-wide change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do like the idea, however it has been declined multiple times by the network at large. I think this is the canonical post:

[Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window)

And I'm not 100% certain, but I suspect we couldn't get an exception for our site.

Because so many other sites don't bother to do this, I've become quite accustomed to right-clicking all links. *And, to be clear: I don't just mean other sites in the SE network, but the entire Internet.*

Comment: Oh well...worth trying. I usually use the CTRL button but often times forget when reading.